# azure mobile service not working on xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement Azure Mobile Services in my Xamarin.Forms app.

I'm following [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/xamarin.forms) link and it works on iOS but not on Android.
It throws this exception:

> MobileServiceInvalidOperationException - "The server did not provide a response with the expected content."

I have tried switching between HTTP and HTTPS but could not get it working.
It works on Android (native) as well, just not on Xamarin.Android

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/467), and seems to be because of the following:

> we don't support .Net Core 2.1 in the SDK today. Unfortunately, we don't have a workaround today and like Ela said, the we don't have an ETA for a new release or other SDK to use for .Net Core 2.1 compatibility yet, so your only workaround is to stick with .Net Core 2.0 for now.

There seems to be a temporary work around [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/514), by brendanzagaeski to in the call to new MobileServiceClient():

- Either pass in an HttpClientHandler instance
- Or pass in an instance of AndroidClientHandler

It seems like AndroidClientHandler is the one that works the most often.

Comment: passing an AndroidClientHandler resolved the issue.

Comment: @Awais Shaikh  What else do I need to do to make this work please?
I am creating my mobile service client like this:

 public static MobileServiceClient MobileServiceAndroid =
            new MobileServiceClient(Constants.AzureURL, new HttpClientHandler());

Then tried to pull from the table like this:
                    regionList = await App.MobileServiceAndroid.GetTable<Models.Region>().ToListAsync();
                
But I assume there's a delegate class to create? Please advise how to fix this. I am still getting the error mentioned above.

Comment: @Saamer can you please explain more in detail how you solved this problem I am still getting the error please.

Comment: Hey @razvan! Do you have the same error message? What error message do you get? Did you try to replace the httpclienthandler with Androidclienthandler?

Comment: @RazvanEmil ^ this would translate into public static MobileServiceClient MobileServiceAndroid = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.AzureURL, new AndroidClientHandler());

Comment: @Saamer I cannot use AndroidClientHandler because I am calling this in the PCL (Shared project), there are no Android specific libraries, unless i maybe use dependency injection. Yes I get same error only for Android. It was better if I could use HttpClientHandler. But I do not understand for sure, clienthandler means I need to delegate some code to get the table in a separate class?

Comment: @RazvanEmil try to create a separate question, and lets see what issues you have there. Is it only on Android as well?

Comment: @Saamer yes only on android.

Comment: Can you try to use a custom renderer that will let you use the AndroidClientHandler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 0):

Check if "microsoft.azure.mobile.client" is referenced on your project. If not, try installing a lower version of the "microsoft.azure.mobile.client" through nuget package on your project add the using directive and then update the "microsoft.azure.mobile.client" through nuget package.
And update any pending package.