# Xamarin.Android Cannot pull table from Azure database in Android 10 Q

Tags: azure, http, xamarin, xamarin.android

I did read that because lack of support for Netcore 2.1 the

```
myItemsList = await App.MobileServiceAndroid.GetTable<MyTable>().ToListAsync();
```

does not currently work on Android, and there is a workaround to pass an HttpClientHandler() in the constructor of the MobileServiceClient, and so I did like this:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileServiceAndroid =
            new MobileServiceClient(AppConstants.AZURE_PRODUCTION_WEB_API_URL, new HttpClientHandler());
```

But this is incomplete,its still not working, what exactly do I have to do to make this work, any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you are using a Forms/PCL project whereas the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58223264/11104068) was implementing this code inside their Android project.
For you, once you add `using Xamarin.Android.Net;` to the class, you should be able to just do this:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileServiceAndroid =
            new MobileServiceClient(AppConstants.AZURE_PRODUCTION_WEB_API_URL, new AndroidClientHandler());
```

---

Most likely you might have issues getting that using statement, for that you will have to follow steps shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/code), or customized for you in the following steps:

1. Add the Xamarin Forms project to all your projects.
2. Create an interface `ICustomClientHandler` in the Core project

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Test
{
    public interface ICustomClientHandler
    {
        HttpClientHandler GetHandler();
    }
}
```

3. Then create a `CustomClientHandler` in the Droid project, which will be the Android part of the dependency service that will help you retrieve the native AndroidClientHandler

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Xamarin.Android.Net;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Test;
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Test.Droid.CustomClientHandler))]
namespace Test.Droid
{
    public class CustomClientHandler : ICustomClientHandler
    {
        public HttpClientHandler GetHandler()
        {
            return new AndroidClientHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

4. Implement an iOS version as well in a similar way, but it will instead `return new HttpClientHandler();`
5. Finally, use the code as shown, in your Core project:

```
var clientHandler = DependencyService.Get<ICustomClientHandler>().GetHandler();
public static MobileServiceClient MobileServiceAndroid =
            new MobileServiceClient(AppConstants.AZURE_PRODUCTION_WEB_API_URL, clientHandler);
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work thanks for taking the time. I get an error "Resource Not Found"

Comment: Where do you get that error? Is it runtime or compile time?

Comment: the error is at runtime. Should this not work but connecting directly with via HTTP to the database, using the connection string? Just not sure how you would do that exactly.

Comment: @Sammer I will give it a try later today.